# flask.request mocker.patch.object does not take effect

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, pytest

In my controller I got this endpoint:

```
@bp_crawler.route('/insert', methods=['POST'])
def insert_data():
    req = requests.CrawledSocialDataRequest.from_json(json.loads(request.data))
```

And then, I try to test this with `pytest` and `pytest-mock` for the `mocker` fixture.

I proceed to mock the `request` object so that the `request.data` returns some value that is useful for my unit testing.

```
# arrange
data_to_insert = requests.CrawledSocialDataRequest([
    requests.CrawledSocialDataRecord('cid0', 'content0', 123.4, ['tag0', 'tag1']),
    requests.CrawledSocialDataRecord('cid1', 'content1', 123.4, ['tag1', 'tag2'])
])
request_mock = mocker.patch.object(flask, 'request')
request_mock.data = data_to_insert.serialize()

db_mock = request_mock = mocker.patch.object(api, 'db')

# act
result = controller.insert_data()
```

Everything is fine, except when the `insert_data()` is called.

I get the following exception:

```
    controllers/v1/tests/test_crawler.py:30: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    controllers/v1/crawler.py:36: in insert_data
        req = requests.CrawledSocialDataRequest.from_json(json.loads(request.data))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py:347: in __getattr__
        return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py:306: in _get_current_object
        return self.__local()


name = 'request'

    def _lookup_req_object(name):
        top = _request_ctx_stack.top
        if top is None:
>           raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
E           RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
E           
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
E           information about how to avoid this problem.
```

The mock does not take place and thus the request.data routes control to the `flask.globals`, having my unit test to fail.

Github links:

- [Controller](https://github.com/deepettas/algotrading-api/blob/master/controllers/v1/crawler.py)
- [Test](https://github.com/deepettas/algotrading-api/blob/master/controllers/v1/tests/test_crawler.py)

Comment: https://github.com/deepettas/algotrading-api/blob/master/controllers/v1/tests/test_crawler.py and test return a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if on the `_test.py` you do:

```
import flask
...
request_mock = mocker.patch.object(flask, 'request')
```

But on your controller/endpoint, you do

```
from flask import request
...
x = request.data # this will break
```

So, you have to do `import flask -> x = flask.request.data` for this to work, or change mocking techniques.

Answer (score -1):

You can mock the request from the controller rather than from flask, for example:

```
request_mock = mocker.patch('controllers.v1.crawler.request')
request_mock.data = data_to_insert.serialize()
```

Comment: This is a TERRIBLE idea, using string constants that can not be type checked, refactored, and so on.

Comment: You can also do this is your prefer: `request_mock = mocker.patch.object(crawler, 'request')`, the point is you don't need to change your business logic to handle mocking the request.